# Кобениться

Tags: этимология

Скажите, пожалуйста, каково происхождение слова "кобениться", "выкобениваться"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кобениться. Происходит от неустановленной формы. Русск. ко́бень «твердолобый, своенравный, жеманный человек», кобе́нить, кобе́ня «крюк на стене, [ломака, кривляка]» и т. п. сравнивают с лит. kãbė «крюк», латышск. kаbа, kabe «стропило», лит. kabė́ti «висеть», латышск. kabinât — то же, лит. kabẽklis, kebẽklis «крюк». Связь со ст.-слав. кобь «augurium» невероятна. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.